# How to get the date from the date picker in django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, css, django

I am trying to get the date from the user using date picker in django. But I am just getting none despite user picking up a date .  I followed this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html

I am trying to get the date using the cleaned.data.

```
date = form.cleaned_data['date']
```

How do I get the date user selects. Also, I want the hour  and minute field in date picker

This is my date field in the form (I am using forms.form)

```
 class DateForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateTimeField(
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'],
        widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control datetimepicker-input',
            'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'
        })
    )
```

Here is the code in my HTML file

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have manually added the `<input>` to the HTML, but missed the important `name` parameter. Without this, the field value isn't included in the POST and the server never sees it.

Add `name="date"` and it should work ok.

The tutorial used `{{ form.date }}` for a reason - to make it harder to screw it up.